# In my project `venv`, `python3 manage.py runserver` will get error, but if I use the absolute path python3 to execute this will be okay

Tags: python, virtualenv

In my project `venv`, `python3 manage.py runserver` will get error:

```
...
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)
AttributeError: module 'socketio' has no attribute 'Server'
```

but if I use the absolute path python3 to execute this will be okay.

```
# /usr/local/Python3/bin/python3.5 manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
... 
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
(27144) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

But if I check the python3 path in `venv`:

```
(venv_dist) [root@www lll]# ll /home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv_dist/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 5月   9 10:43 /home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv_dist/bin/python3 -> python3.5
(venv_dist) [root@www lll]# ll /home/ldl/repo/myProjecg/venv_dist/bin/python3.5
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 32 5月   9 10:43 /home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv_dist/bin/python3.5 -> /usr/local/Python3/bin/python3.5
```

You see, the `python3` in `venv` redirect to the `/usr/local/Python3/bin/python3.5` at last.

the absolute path `python3` can execute success:

```
/usr/local/Python3/bin/python3.5 manage.py runserver
```

but the soft link `python3` can not run success.

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

My system is CentOS-7.

---

**EDIT-1**

Use which:

```
which python3
/home/ldl/repo/myProject/venv_dist/bin/python3
```

Use `python` runserver:

```
(venv_dist) [root@www myProject]# python --version
Python 3.5.2
(venv_dist) [root@www myProject]# python manage.py runserver
```

there get the upper error.

---

**EDIT-2**

inside the venv:

```
(venv_dist) [root@www myProject]# pip3 freeze | grep -i socketio
python-socketio==1.9.0
socketio==0.0.9
```

outside the vevn:

```
[root@www myProject]# pip3 freeze | grep -i socketio
python-socketio==1.8.4
```

---

**EDIT -3**

And outside the project, I also can runserver.
It's point to the `/usr/local/Python3/bin/python3` too.

```
[root@www myProject]# python3 manage.py runserver
...
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
(28747) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8000
^C[root@www myProject]# which python3 
/usr/bin/python3
[root@www myProject]# ll /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 30 12月 10 14:17 /usr/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/Python3/bin/python3
```

---

**EDIT-4**

I think this `socketio` package have nothing to do with the issue, in my project I `pip3 uninstall socketio`, this issue still exists.

But if in my Mac, if I uninstall the `socketio` in my `venv`, there will get the issue too.

```
...
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)
AttributeError: module 'socketio' has no attribute 'Server'
```

in my Mac I have to reinstall the `socketio` in the `venv`, then it can works fine.

---

**EDIT-5**

In my remote CentOS7.2 server, `ls` the `venv_dist`, there is a soft-link `lib64` refer to the `lib`.

```
(venv_dist) [root@www venv_dist]# ls
bin  include  lib  lib64  pip-selfcheck.json  pyvenv.cfg
```

But in my Mac, there is no `lib64`.

Comment: What if you run `python manage.py runserver` in the venv? Also, what does `which python3` give?

Comment: @Railslide See my Edit -1, whether is caused by I did not use the `python2.7` as the python?

Comment: Could you post the outcome of `pip3 freeze | grep -i socketio` from both outside and inside the venv?

Comment: @Railslide Have done. See my eidt-2.

Comment: Sounds like you installed 2 different packages with socketio modules inside your venv, and the "socketio" one doesn't have the API your code is expecting.

Comment: @geoffspear Hi, bro, I get the big discover. see my `EDIT-4`.